# Не могу собрать и установит gRPC c++

Tags: c++, библиотеки, сборка, grpc

Пытаюсь собрать grpс с помощью cmake. Проект нормально собирается, но на этапе установке с помощью make install выдает ошибку

```
make install

Installing via 'make' is no longer supported. Use cmake or bazel instead.

Please consult BUILDING.md to get more information.

make: *** [Makefile:773: stop] Ошибка 1
```

Не знаю что делать, потому что в репозитории grpc указан именно этот способ установки.
Пример компилится, но когда я пытаюсь подключить grpc в свой проект с помощью cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(grpc_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(grpc_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(grpc_test gRPC::grpc++)
```

Cmake выдает слудющую ошибку

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/anton/.local/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake

  but it set gRPC_FOUND to FALSE so package "gRPC" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:
  protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotoc
```

Comment: Отлично ставится и собирается cmake

Comment: cmake --build . --target install

Comment: @JK_Action, Проект собрался, но в конце все равно была эта ошибка. Пример собрался, я попробовал подключить grpc в свой проект, но cmake ругается. В правке оставли свой cmake и ошибку. Не могли бы вы привести пример прсотенького cmake файла для проекта с grpc

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/src/cpp/README.md все тут расписано, заводите отдельный вопрос с конкретными проблемами. А  этот бестолковый я бы закрыл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было добавить в cmake файл find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED), а ошибка при сборки возникала потому что я делал без root прав, добавление sudo к каждой каждой команде решило проблему